# Parse HTML Table to datagrid in VB2010

Tags: html

I want to parse the HTML table from my local HTML file and transfer the contents to datagrid in my VB2010 project.

Here is my table structure:

```html
<table id="ctl00_pageContentPlaceHolder_qisTestEntryGridView" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:auto;font-size:8pt;font-family:'Courier New'">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">TEST_ENTRY_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">ITEM_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">SERIAL_NO</th>
    <th scope="col">REV</th>
    <th scope="col">TEST_DATE</th>
    <th scope="col">STAGE_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">PASS_FAIL</th>
    <th scope="col">TEST_TYPE_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">CHANGED_BY</th>
    <th scope="col">LOCATION_ID</th>
    <th scope="col">WORK_ORDER</th>
    <th scope="col">ERR_CODE</th>
    <th scope="col">COMMENTS</th>
    <th scope="col">PROC_SEQ</th>
    <th scope="col">SESSION_ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>956839</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>9/8/2014 8:19:11 AM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20140908081730</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>957152</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>9/8/2014 10:16:18 AM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20140908101445</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>963615</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>9/12/2014 3:24:08 PM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20140912152225</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1016696</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>10/27/2014 10:10:21 AM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20141027100858</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1017055</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>10/27/2014 9:28:07 PM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20141027212621</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1019666</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>10/29/2014 9:19:02 AM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20141029091733</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1106557</td>
    <td>820-9137-1R</td>
    <td>1A1436PB179935</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>12/20/2014 8:38:56 AM</td>
    <td>1985</td>
    <td>P</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1005</td>
    <td>181</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>181_20141220083707</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to search (id="ctl00_pageContentPlaceHolder_qisTestEntryGridView") once the content exist need to transfer to my datagrid.

The contents data will not fix, depending on the record whether the data exist or not.

Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: Did you look at the HTML agility pack before posting this question? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

It allows for parsing HTML and then XPATH style querying. So assume you know the format (and you do) you could load the HTML via that and run XPATH style queries to get the ID You wanted.

Comment: Hi Bill thanks for your advice, i have been tried but still confuse with the HTML agility pack as it new for me. appreciate if someone to help me with some code to how to get the table info and transfer into the datagrid in vb2010. thanks a lot.

Comment: Still not luck, Can someone help me with some sample?